# getBoundingClientRect deviation between page loads, alternative?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to make an animated category navigation panel and I want the highlighted background to move to the selected category: https://gyazo.com/78119b65275f1905bdb8f5ff03ea4746

To do so, I dynamically use getBoundingClientRect to obtain the proper positions of where the block should go. Although between page loads, the values sometimes randomly are offset for no reason and look like this: https://gyazo.com/798be154e3817261bd8f0aa3ec40ac2d

My code is rather simple and I don't understand if there is a way to fix this or if I have to find some other way that avoids getBoundingClientRect.

```
const projectCategories = document.getElementById("project-categories");
const selector = document.getElementById("category-selector");
const offset = projectCategories.getBoundingClientRect();
const offsetX = offset.left;
console.log(offsetX);
const offsetY = offset.top;
function moveSelector(selector, left, width, height, offsetX, offsetY) {
    selector.style.width = width + "px";
    selector.style.height = height + "px";
    selector.style.transform = "translateX(" + (left - offsetX) + "px)";
}
const initialCategory = document.getElementById("project-categories").getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
const meta = initialCategory.getBoundingClientRect();
const top = meta.top;
moveSelector(selector, meta.left, meta.width, meta.height, offsetX, offsetY);
selector.style.top = (top - offsetY) + "px";
projectCategories.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.nodeName === "A") {
        const meta = target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const height = meta.height;
        const width = meta.width;
        const left = meta.left;
        projectCategories.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
        target.classList.add("active");
        moveSelector(selector, left, width, height, offsetX, offsetY);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be ideal if you could create an example using something like jsfiddle, codepen, or S/O's own. I'd recommend opening up the debugger so you can see and manipulate the values your dealing with; that may help isolate the issue

Comment: I've already tried that. All I know is the bounding values change on random page load intervals.

Comment: in coding (hopefully) things don't change randomly between loads, there is probably a specific cause. If you can reproduce your issue in a jsfiddle, codepen, or snippet here, it will help greatly more experienced people to find the reason why..

Comment: How are you starting the process of executing javascript? If you don't listen for the 'load' or 'DOMContentLoaded' events on the window object, your code's behaviour is entirely unremarkable and precisely why one should listen for either of those events on the window object.

Comment: I forgot to mention it is being initiated on window.onload

Comment: @WillBDev - Hmmmm. Since there's insufficient code in this question to replicate and observe the behaviour you mention, I'll suggest what I'd try. Before executing the code-block that fails, get a count of all elements on the page and print it to the console. I'd then compare the element count between a successful and a failed load and see if I had to work out what wasn't loaded. `var elemCount = document.querySelectorAll('*').length` - this page currently returns 1349

Comment: You can also try to look for other styling actions that could be initiated at `window.load` by other scripts too and that could be unfinished whan you get the bounds.